# Locating Files Outside Folders

Tags: php, mysql, file-io

I need help with writing a php code that allows you to locate files outside a current folder.
supposing  I have this directory

```
......./folders/codes
```

where my current file `index.php` is but then I want to reference a file in folders via the file in code, how do I go about that?

I thought i could use the HTML/CSS way where ***../*** would move you down one folder but it did not work when i tried it

```
require "../Login.php";------------------it failed
```

Comment: Please add more details: is it Windows or Linux? Is it a dedicated server or a shared one?

Comment: I'm using a windows system and Working through the localhost(xampp);

Comment: Isn't it "wamp" then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dirname return you the path up to your parent directory.

Try to use following code

```
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'Login.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

You sure your path is correct?

A common mistake is to overlook from where you're `require`-ing.

If, for example, you were to have a script that was included in another script, the relative path would not be the one you'd think it would be.

Try

```
echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

To see if you didn't make that mistake.
<sub>Not sure if this is appropriate, but it didn't fit in a comment.</sub>

Comment: this is really helpful yeah i had to use this to find the right path thank you